# Does the density of a stick change according to special theory of relativity? Provided the stick is moving at nearly the speed of light?

Tags: special-relativity

[The  equation in the image made me think of the density case in special theory of relativity !](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4modv.jpg)

Comment: It would be helpful if you could actually *write* a question rather than just posting an equation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure it does. If the stick has a linear density $\lambda=m/x$ where x is the length, then if it's moving at velocity $v$ away from you, the length would appear to be:

$$x'=\frac{x}{\gamma}$$

where:

$$\gamma=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-(v/c)^2}}$$

the, the density measured by the observer would be:

$$\lambda'=\lambda\gamma$$

And because $\gamma>1$, it would appear to be more dense.